# export Gridview to Excel using ClosedXML without warning: the file you are trying to open is in a different format

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel, closedxml

I am working on a ASP.NET 4.5 Webform and I have a Gridview (that has custom TemplateField and gets data from a sqlDataSource)

I have this event to export the gridview contents to an excel sheet, and it does its jobs well except the created file is giving out an warning when user open it (which I understand because the file that got created is not an actual excel file):

> "the file you are trying to open is in a different format than
>   specified by the file extension"

```
protected void btnExport_Excel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GV.xls");
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                //Response.ContentType = "application/text";
                Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
                Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());

                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
                {
                    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

                    //To Export all pages
                    GridView4.AllowPaging = false;
                    GridView4.AllowSorting = false;
                    GridView4.ShowFooter = false;
                    GridView4.DataBind();
                    //this.BindGrid();

                    GridView4.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
                    foreach (TableCell cell in GridView4.HeaderRow.Cells)
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = GridView4.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
                    }
                    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView4.Rows)
                    {
                        row.BackColor = Color.White;
                        foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                        {
                            if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                            {
                                cell.BackColor = GridView4.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cell.BackColor = GridView4.RowStyle.BackColor;
                            }
                            cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                        }
                    }

                    GridView4.RenderControl(hw);

                    //style to format numbers to string
                    string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
                    Response.Write(style);
                    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }

                //Display message
                InfoPanel.Visible = true;
                InfoPanel.CssClass = "panel panel-success";
                lblMessage.CssClass = "text text-sucess bold";
                lblMessage.Text = "File has been exported!";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Display message
                InfoPanel.Visible = true;
                lblMessage.Text = "<b>An error has occurred. Please try again later!</b></br>" + ex.Message;
                lblMessage.CssClass = "text text-danger bold";
                InfoPanel.CssClass = "panel panel-danger";
                panelResult.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

the result in the Excel .xls file is good (no styles except header columns, no footer, just exact as shown on the Gridview):

[image]

---

I am finding another way to avoid this warning, so I see people like to use
[ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/documentation?referringTitle=Home), so I replace that event above with this event:

```
protected void ExportExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("GridView_Data");
    foreach(TableCell cell in GridView4.HeaderRow.Cells)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text);
    }
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView4.Rows)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();
        for (int i=0; i<row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
        }
   }
    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GV.xlsx");

        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

and the result is bad (only good new is that the exported file is a real 2007+ Excel sheet so no warnings):
[image]

How do I get the "good" result above using closedXML?

Comment: Have you checked the DataTable before inserting it into the worksheet? You may have to call `dt.AcceptChanges();` before after adding the data to the DataTable.

Comment: just put it in but still same result?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are happy with the second excel (closedXML) but the data is not displaying?

Comment: yes, I want to use ClosedXML to export a real excel file but headers and  data are not displaying, something wrong with the code.

Comment: you are going about this in the wrong way why are you parsing the headers etc.. you can accomplish this with much less code using ClosedXML I will post a working example that you can follow.. I use ClosedXML on a daily basis with zero issues.

Comment: Try to save the file with a `.html` extension, but still specifying content type as Excel. Rationale: you're using the old Office HTML format, and Excel is quite capable of opening HTML files.

Comment: Is there a reason you are exporting the GridView rather than the data that you bound to the GridView? That would really simplify your code and make more logical sense.

Comment: for example a datetime data looks like `2016-01-02 00:00:00.000` in database but in Gridview I only want to display date only, another example would be a "status" data, raw data in database is an integer (1, 2, 3 etc.) but when displaying to Gridview 1 = "Pending", 2 = "Approved" and so on... so I want to export those "processed" data in Gridview, not the raw data.

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding Then that should be part of your export processing code. It's better to export the underlying data and manipulate it from there rather than taking your GridView. Now you've needlessly coupled your export to what your GridView is showing. Messy.

Comment: @mason I don't quite get what you say, so I have already done the "formatting" job - basically make the Gridview display "good" in the web page, and that is also what I want to show in the excel sheet, there is no reason to repeat the "formatting" job again, instead just export that extract Gridview, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, there is a very good reason for repeating the formatting. They're different. An Excel file's formatting is not defined by HTML. It has its own way of doing things. And HTML has its own way. Trying to get Excel to do HTML is a recipe for inflexible code.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem in you second part of code (with ClosedXML) , that you are trying to use `Text` property of `GridViewRow` for `TemplateField` field columns. As you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can get field value via `Text` property only for `BoundField` field columns and automatically generated field columns.

To get value from `TemplateField` you should navigate to inner control which contains value and get value  from it.

If you have the following column template:

```
   <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="labelName" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("ABC")%>' ></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

Your code should be:

```
    for (int i=0; i<row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = (row.Cells[i].FindControl("labelName") as Label).Text;
    }
```

**EDIT**

Your code should be as follows:

```
protected void ExportExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("GridView_Data");
    foreach (DataControlField col in GridView4.Columns)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText);
    }
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView4.Rows)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = (FindControl(row.Cells[i].Controls, "lbl") as Label).Text;
        }
    }
    //your code below is not changed
}

protected Control FindControl(ControlCollection collection, string id)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in collection)
    {
        if (ctrl.ID == id)
            return ctrl;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Ensure that all `Label` controls used in `TemplateField` have the same `ID` as `"lbl"`:

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("ID")%>' ></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("Name")%>' ></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("Amount")%>' ></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: How do I get all the headers, in my code I have something like `<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="Amount" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">`

Comment: Also can you help with the loop, so I have like 7 ItemTemplate, most are labels, how do I get the data? It's would be really helpful if you can show a complete function or the codes/loop that will get the data.

Comment: I still can't get this working, can you show an example, assume that there are 5 `TemplateField` (with `HeaderText`), each has 1 `ItemTemplate` which contain 1 `label`. How your functions look like?

Comment: I've changed answer. I hope it will help you to solve the problem.

Comment: For the header column, got an err: `'object' does not contain a definition for 'HeaderText' and no extension method 'HeaderText' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: I was looking at these articles, can you take a look at them: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1027572/Gridview-Export-To-Excel-xlsx-with-TemplateField and this: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-with-TemplateField-Column-to-Excel-in-ASPNet.aspx to find out? Your code was not working?

Comment: I did a small fix. Everything works correctly for me.

Answer (score 4):

I tried it's working ,please find the code hope it will help you:

**Index.aspx**

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="ExportExcel.Index" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle- ForeColor="White"
        runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="30"  />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" Text='<%# Eval("Country") %>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnExport" Text="Export" runat="server" OnClick="btnExport_Click" />
</div>
</form>
```

**Index.aspx.cs**

```
        using ClosedXML.Excel;
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.IO;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.UI;
        using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

   namespace ExportExcel
    {
    public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            GetData();
        }
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("Country", typeof(string)) });
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "abc", "UK");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "def", "India");
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "ghi", "France");
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "jkl", "Russia");
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("GridView_Data");
            foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text);
            }
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                TextBox txtNameRow = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtName");

                Label lblCountryRow = (Label)row.FindControl("lblCountry");

                DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    drow[i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
                }
                drow["Name"] = txtNameRow.Text;
                drow["Country"] = lblCountryRow.Text;
                dt.Rows.Add(drow);
            }
            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GV.xlsx");

                using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }




}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I call the Export to Excel on a button click event like the following

```
protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fileName = string.Format(fileName, DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy_hhmmss"));
    Extensions.ExportToXcel_SomeReport(dt, fileName, this.Page);
}
```

from there I have a utils class called `Extensions` where I have the `ExportToExcel_SomeReport` method defined

```
public static class Extensions
{
     internal static void ExportToXcel_SomeReport(DataTable dt, string fileName, Page page)
    {
        var recCount = dt.Rows.Count;
        RemoveHtmlSpecialChars(dt);
        fileName = string.Format(fileName, DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy_hhmmss"));
        var xlsx = new XLWorkbook();
        var ws = xlsx.Worksheets.Add("Some Report Name");
        ws.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        ws.Cell("C5").Value = "YOUR REPORT NAME";
        ws.Cell("C5").Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Black;
        ws.Cell("C5").Style.Font.SetFontSize(16.0);
        ws.Cell("E5").Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
        ws.Range("C5:E5").Style.Font.SetFontSize(16.0);
        ws.Cell("A7").Value = string.Format("{0} Records", recCount);
        ws.Style.Font.Bold = false;
        ws.Cell(9, 1).InsertTable(dt.AsEnumerable());
        ws.Row(9).InsertRowsBelow(1);
       // ws.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Gray;
        ws.Columns("1-9").AdjustToContents();
        ws.Tables.Table(0).ShowAutoFilter = true;
        ws.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
        DynaGenExcelFile(fileName, page, xlsx);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Remove all HTML special characters from datatable field if they are present 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dt"></param>
    private static void RemoveHtmlSpecialChars(DataTable dt)
    {
        for (int rows = 0; rows < dt.Rows.Count; rows++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < dt.Columns.Count; column++)
            {
                dt.Rows[rows][column] = dt.Rows[rows][column].ToString().Replace("&nbsp;", string.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Call this Method to Generate the Excel Files from different Lap Reports depending on which one has been selected
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <param name="page"></param>
    /// <param name="xlsx"></param>
    private static void DynaGenExcelFile(string fileName, Page page, XLWorkbook xlsx)
    {
        page.Response.ClearContent();
        page.Response.ClearHeaders();
        page.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        page.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xlsx", fileName));

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            xlsx.SaveAs(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.WriteTo(page.Response.OutputStream);
        }
        page.Response.Flush();
        page.Response.End();
    }   

}
```

Comment: This method serves an XLSX file up with the MIME type of an XLS file and using the .XLS file extension. It would be better to use the proper extension and MIME type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`.

Comment: @mason I am using ClosedXML and I am well aware.. if you have a better working version by all means please post an it as an answer

Comment: I do not understand your comment. You're serving an XLSX file with the MIME type used by an XLS file. You need to use the correct MIME type. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @mason I have given the example using the type that I was testing with as it also works using the xlsx type I will update the answer it's as simple as that..!

Comment: I see you made a 1 character edit, but it still has the wrong MIME type.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to popular belief, you can set the extension of your file to be .html, and Excel can open it up.

[image]

Just set the extension to HTML:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GV.html");
```

And retain Excel as the content type:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
```

EDIT: Oh, right, forgot to mention, this should make that annoying dialog go away.

EDIT 2: Looks like the original question has changed... now it's talking about using ClosedXML... but I'll leave this answer here just in case someone else is using HTML and Excel.

Comment: Just because you can does not mean you should. The MIME type should accurately describe the content. It's then up to the user's settings to determine what to open the file with.

Comment: @mason: I'm referring to the original office HTML specs. Which used to exist on MSDN, but apparently not there anymore. Which, however, is *still* supported. Hence if you decide to save a datatable to HTML and then open it in Excel, it will quite easily do that for you.